# Get active view of sharepoint list by JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, view

How can I get the current view (the selected view) ID of a sharepoint list by using Javascript Object Model?

Answer (score 6):

**SharePoint 2010**

Use `ClientContext` structure that is generated on the client-side and contains List View details:

```
//find active View Id
function getCurrentViewId(listId)
{
  var viewId;
  for(var ctxKey in g_ctxDict){
     var curCtx = g_ctxDict[ctxKey];
     if(curCtx.listName == listId){
        viewId = curCtx.view;
        break; 
     }
  }
  return viewId;
}  

var activeListId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var activeViewId = getCurrentViewId(activeListId);
getListView(activeListId,activeViewId, 
       function(view){
         console.log(view.get_title());
       },
       function(sendera,args){
         console.log(args.get_message());
     });
```

**SharePoint 2013**

In addition to capabilities available in SharePoint 2010, you could consider the following approach.

Use `SP.ListOperation.ViewOperation.getSelectedView()` method or `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedView()` method from [SP.ListOperation namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj244766(v=office.15).aspx) to retrieve `active` View Id, the following example demonstrates how to retrieve View details:

```
var activeListId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var activeViewId = SP.ListOperation.ViewOperation.getSelectedView();

getListView(activeListId,activeViewId, 
   function(view){
       console.log(view.get_title());
   },
   function(sendera,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

### How to get View using SharePoint JSOM

```
function getListView(listId,viewId,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
   var view = list.get_views().getById(viewId);
   ctx.load(view);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          success(view); 
      },
      error);
}
```

Comment: Great answer. FYI, I am on SP 2013 and I found that `g_ctxDict` doesn't contain anything inside it in a page containing list view webpart. The length of the dictionary is zero.

Comment: Thanks, Nadeem! Regarding SharePoint 2013, hmm.. i could access it, probably the length is because it is not an array but an object(!), you could try to see it's content like this: console.log(g_ctxDict)  ;)

Comment: This guy always give great answers with the details. Like you :)

Comment: hi guy, `var activeViewId = SP.ListOperation.ViewOperation.getSelectedView();` sometime doesn't work?

Comment: The 
SP.ListOperation only works when the items of list is selected. Are there any ways without selecting the item?