# Get current view id in js

Tags: javascript, document-library, csom, view

For a development i need to get the current view in a library.
I added a content editor webpart on allitems.aspx that links to a js file. inside i have to get the current view id.
I can have listid but viewid is always null

Here is how i do

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var listID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
console.log("listID="+listID);
var viewID = SP.ListOperation.ViewOperation.getSelectedView();
console.log("listID ="+viewID );//here is null
```

I've searched in google without succes

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ideally your code is correct and it should work.... please refer below link some more details are given here... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125436/get-active-view-of-sharepoint-list-by-jsom

Comment: I follow this post but it doesn't work. it returns null

Comment: Wrap your code in a function and try executing your code using ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListViewId, "sp.js");

Answer (score 2):

In a Library View (thus ONE ListView WebPart on the page) the view ID is in:

```
_spPageContextInfo.viewId
```

and..

the list ID is:

```
_spPageContextInfo.listId
```

that `_spPageContextInfo` object has a whole lot more you might be interested in.. inspect it in F12 dev tools..

Comment: Hi, i use your solution but it's undefined in my case. (i have a content editor webpart on my page documentlibrary that load a js file)

Comment: Then you are probably trying to access it before the page is done loading ``_spPageContextInfo`` is core SharePoint functionality

Comment: if i look with developer tool i have: _spPageContextInfo.pageListId but no other guid. Here is which properties i have: http://sympmarc.com/2013/03/26/using-_sppagecontextinfo-to-determine-the-current-sharepoint-context-in-script/

Comment: That is a blog from 2013, the link in my reply is 3 years younger...

Comment: I trust you but in my SP2013 Foundation i have only the properties i showed you. Do you know an other solution to get current view?

Comment: Ah! 2013 Foundation...Yes, they are only available in the newer stuff. IDs are also included in the DOM. Maybe this gets you something: ``document.querySelector("table [class='ms-listviewtable']").getAttribute('view')``